# pass content of contenteditable to input value and process in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

html code structure is as it follows a simple form

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div contenteditable="true" id="post"></div>
  <input type="text" name="postHiddenField" id="postHidden" hidden>
  <button type="submit" name="submitPost">Post</button>
</form>
```

beneath the form the javascript is a simple atribute

```
var content = document.getElementById('post').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('postHidden').value = content;
```

on top of the form is the form being proccessed

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitPost'])) {
   if (!empty($_POST['postHiddenField'])) {
        echo $_POST['postHiddenField'];
   } else {
      echo "field is empty";
   }
}
?>
```

result i get on submission is field is empty
how to proper get content's editable content and pass it to the hidden field as value?

Comment: The script you have is only executed exactly *once*, when the page loads. It doesn't magically extend into the future. If you wrap it in a function and set it as the form's `onsubmit`, it should work.

Comment: hey its working

Comment: how secure is this practice?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: in terms of javascript i mean can be the code hacked or everything lies on php process?

Comment: Any JS browser code can be altered, yes. So you always have to validate all user input on the server, too. Especially when you're calling DB queries based on it.